# Sum number with range array

Tags: python, arrays, list

```
temp= np.array([[   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 1000,    0,    0,
                    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
                [   0,    0, 3000, 2000,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,
                    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0],
                [   0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0,    0, 1500,    0,    0,    0,
                    0,    0,    0,  500,    0,    0,    0]])
```

How to sum numbers in range 1000 to 2000 and keep column number? For example in the second row it should skip 3000 and collect 2000 and keep column index = 3, in the third row sum 1500 and 500 and collect column index 7 and 14.

Answer (score 1):

I feel like you've asked two questions here.
First to find indices that satisfy a condition:

```
np.where((temp >= 1000) & (temp <= 2000))
```

Output (with column number for each row):

```
(array([0, 1, 2], dtype=int64), array([8, 3, 7], dtype=int64))
```

Secondly to sum, just use `np.sum`:

```
np.sum(temp[(temp >= 1000) & (temp <= 2000)])
```